# How to import module files in to a program?

Tags: wi-fi, device-firmware

Supossing i have a folder **update** from a **update_full.zip** that contains:

```
OTA_update.tag
PTABLE.APP
ptable.img
sec_xloader_header
SOFTWARE_VER.mbn
SOFTWARE_VER_LIST.mbn
UPDATE.APP
UPT_VER.tag
VERSION.mbn
```

I want to compile an app or execute a serie of command instructions (maybe from a terminal emulator) and take as import modules certain files from **update** folder, for example to be specific i want to *"Replicate"* Bluetooth activation (as work in settings) but externally, is it not necessary to act entirely as original but maybe connect to other devices and listening for connections, i am a bit new to android programming and developing apps but once i get some basic knownledge about network locations inside this folder (`WI-FI`, `BLUETOOTH`) i think i can compile an **apk** file or something like running on a **Termux** session. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: [OP's previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250611/44325) which might be related as additional context.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking, but you cannot install modified update.zip because these zips are signed with Huawei private key (you don't have)